# Mac Catalina constantly asking me which browser to use as the default

Tags: mac, safari, catalina, google-chrome, macos

Mac Catalina is constantly asking me which browser to use as the default - it prompts me with a small modal window with 2 buttons/choices with the options `Keep Safari` or `Use Chrome` - or something very similar.  **NOTE:  I wish I had a screenshot, but I don't right now... next time I get the error I will edit this.**

As best I can figure it, this happens when...

1. I hit the "Update" button (when one is available/ready for Chrome) or...
2. restart my Mac or...
3. Chrome crashes/ends unexpectedly

I've already gone into System Preferences > General > Default Web Browser where it is/has been set to Google Chrome forever, and as far as I can tell, does not ever change.

[image]

I can't figure out why this keeps happening... any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are using handoff. Do you use same browser on your iDevice ?

Comment: @PtitXav thanks so much for the reply!  

What is/how do you know/would I know that I am using Handoff?  I have an iPad mini that I do use with the same login... and I would assume that's what we're talking about... I also have a very old iPad 1 (not even sure it can run Chrome).  In any case, I looked at the iPad mini after reading your comment, and I don't see any way of setting Chrome/or any default browser in settings.  

Thanks again in advance! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Check on newest iPad if it is iOS 14 or newer. In this case go to settings/chrome : there is an option to select the default browser.

Comment: I'll check, but I doubt it... there's lots of SW I can't install on it b/c of iOS is limited I think to v.12.x.  Is there a way I can just turn off the "handoff" function entirely?

Comment: On the mac it is in system  settings / general / handoff

Comment: I see it.  OK, unchecked it... I'll let you know after I reboot again.  Thanks again for your help!  If this works... I'd like to give you credit... why not create an answer?